# NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "0":String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Rails 5.1
```

My migration file:

```
class CreateFwExports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :fw_exports, id: :string do |t|
      t.string :screen_name, index: true, limit: 16
      t.string :full_name, limit: 21
      t.string :location_placeholder

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

From the fw_exports controller:

```
def fw_export_params
  params.require(:fw_export).permit(:screen_name, :full_name, :location_placeholder)
end
```

In the fw_export.rb model, I have:

```
has_one :location
has_many :followers
```

In the location.rb model, I have:

```
belongs_to :fw_export
```

In the follower.rb model, I have:

```
has_many :followed
```

In my helper file, I have the following method:

```
def process_spreadsheet(number_of_rows, spreadsheet, followed_id)
  (1..number_of_rows).each do |i|
    fw_export_record = FwExport.new(
        :screen_name => spreadsheet[i][0],
        :full_name => spreadsheet[i][1],
        :location_placeholder => spreadsheet[i][2],
    )
    fw_export_record.save
    location = Location.new(
        :fw_exports_id => fw_export_record.id
    )
    location.save
    follower = Follower.new(
        :followed_id => followed_id,
        :fw_exports_id => fw_export_record.id
    )
    follower.save       
  end
end
```

What this method does, is receive a spreadsheet CSV object, and iterates through the data, trying to save each row to the fw_exports table. It also creates entries into the locations and followers tables

There is a locations table, with the following fields:

```
t.string :fw_exports_id, index: true
t.string :city
t.string :state
t.string :country
```

and a followers table with the following fields:

```
t.string :followed_id
t.string :fw_exports_id
t.string :slug, index: true
```

When I try to import the data, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "0":String):
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:21:in `block in process_spreadsheet'
app/helpers/fw_exports_helper.rb:20:in `process_spreadsheet'
app/controllers/fw_exports_controller.rb:82:in `process_parsed_spreadsheet'
```

I verified that all the parameters passed to the process_spreadsheet call are valid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a binding.pry right before the each method call and type continue until you hit the error.

Comment: How will that help? I am hitting the error on the first line

Comment: does the line number 21 point to `(1..number_of_rows).each do |i|` ?

Comment: after `fw_export_record.save`, what is the value of `fw_export_record.id`?

Comment: I am not getting to that point. line 21 is the (1..number_of_rows).each do |i| line

Comment: I figured out the issue. I have in my fw_exports model a :followers field. I need to replace it with a :followers_placeholder. The error message is misleading, and I'm trying to understand why I can't have a column, in one model, that's the same name as another model, if they have dependencies on each other

Comment: is `has_many :followed` correct?